# Highcharts - manually trigger hover event on a point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When you hover over a point in a Highcharts chart, you get a nice enlarged circle under you cursor (or other symbol). What I would like to do manually trigger that hover effect.

I know that I can manually trigger the mouseOver event on the point, but that doesn't give me the enlarged symbol on the chart that I am going for.

Comment: When do you want to trigger ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: In my particular case, I want to trigger the effect when hovering over another point. I am aware of the the "shared" flag you can put on the tooltip, but that is not what I am looking for. I want to trigger the hover effect on another point in the same series, but at a different x,y.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the source - call "setState('hover');" on the point that you want to be highlighted.

Comment: and to remove the hover state, call "setState();" with no arguments

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that sets the hover state and shows the tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/xW2MW/ (via the [HighCharts forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7094)).

Comment: just read your answer. excellent!!! I wish I would saw it 2 days ago. would have saved me lot of time and efforts. certainly have my vote...

Comment: I've raised an issue on github for the crosshairs not showing when using `setState('hover')`. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10528

Comment: $("tspan:contains(Your-Legend)").trigger('mouseover');, Tool tip was working, but not setting opacity of other series, but to highlight particular series in case of multiple series, I had to manually trigger mouseover event on legend of that series

Answer (score 12):

Just to add an important information:

For StockChart this solution doesn't work:

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xW2MW/) you have to replace this:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[i]);
```

to this:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[i]]);
```

One possible solution is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JMarques/w5mEH/).

Comment: I had this issue where the refresh on the datapoints was not working, until added the outer [] brackets, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to select (hover) the last valid point in series programmatically:

```
  // Find last not-null point in data
  let last = data.indexOf(null) - 1;
  last = (last === -2) ? data.length - 1 : last;
  const lastPoint = this.series[0].points[last];

  // Trigger the hover event 
  lastPoint.setState('hover');
  lastPoint.state = '';  // You need this to fix hover bug
  this.tooltip.refresh(lastPoint); // Show tooltip
```

[Full JSFiddle exapmle](https://jsfiddle.net/doasync/8nqsoL5f/6/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To give a more direct answer (e.g. for then you don't have access to the highcharts instance):

you need to create a mouseover event and give it proper pageX and pageY attributes before you trigger it.