# Show tooltip of a column chart programmatically in StockChart (highchart)

Tags: ruby, tooltip, highcharts

I've a **Highstock** chart (Line with markers and shadow) and would like to show a highstock tooltip programmatically, i.e. when i select, for example, a row on some table (that contains chart data) i would like to show the corresponding highstock tooltip.

Is that possible?

Comment: Well, i believe that we should reopen this question because i realized that this isn't a duplicate question. My question is about StockChart (and not HighChart like the other link). The solution is slightly different. So please reopen this and i will put the right answer.

Comment: I exactly have the same requirement. How to do this using HighCharts Android Wrapper ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For StockChart [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194527/highcharts-manually-trigger-hover-event-on-a-point) doesn't work:

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xW2MW/) you have to replace this:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[i]);
```

to this:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[i]]);
```

The solution is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JMarques/w5mEH/).

Comment: How to do the same thing using HighCharts android wrapper ?

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is to trigger tooltip *on the plot* near `i`<sup>th</sup> data point, then probaly you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318136/693538), which suggest to do something like

```
chart.series[0].data[i].setState('hover');
```

where `chart` is the result of your `new Highcharts.Chart`. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xW2MW/) from the comments to that answer).

I guess that if you want to do it on `<tr>` click, than your js could finally look like this

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ <your options> });
$('#yourTableId tr').click(function(){
   var i = $(this).index(); // `this` points to <tr>, get its index
   chart.series[0].data[i].setState('hover');
});
```

Comment: Thanks =) That exacty what i want (i didn't find this on my research :S )

Comment: I removed the accepted answer because this solution doesn't work for Highstock chart. Sorry.