# Show tooltip programmatically in StockChart for multiples series (highchart)

Tags: ruby, tooltip, highcharts

I'm working on a stockchart and i would like to show the highstock tooltip programmatically as [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645780/show-tooltip-of-a-column-chart-programmatically-in-stockchart-highchart).

I managed to solve this problem but now, my goal is to show the tooltip  for **all series** (the same behavior when i select a point with the mouse - please check [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare)).

Is that possible?

Here the key code ([more code](http://jsfiddle.net/JMarques/cf7wq/4/)):

```
xchart.tooltip.refresh([xchart.series[0].points[i]]);
//DOESN'T WORK
//chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series.points[i]]);
//DOESN'T WORK ALSO
//chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[i]]);
//chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[1].points[i]]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just enable sharing for tooltip. And refresh both series's tooltip by giving the points of array that you want to show on the tooltip.

```
tooltip : {
          valueDecimals : 2,
          shared: true
}

xchart.tooltip.refresh([xchart.series[0].points[i], xchart.series[1].points[i]]);
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/cf7wq/5/

And seems like showing two different tooltips without sharing is not possible through only api itself.

> http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12670

Comment: If you can identify what serie is being hovered you can show different tooltips, so it's possible using api.

Comment: Can you show an example where you can show two tooltips, I haven't see anything like that that could be handy in the future =)

Comment: Take a look the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225896/highchart-tolltip-for-legends
Of course it can be improved.

Comment: If I haven't miss anything, this is more of a workaround using renderer feature, so basically you draw a tooltip yourself using the renderer. What I think is not possible to show the tooltips related to each point by highchart using tooltip methods. Thanks for the info anyway.