# add markers for specific values in streaming multi line in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, marker, linechart, spline

Here I'm working on Highcharts time series chart with live streaming data, based on the sample jsfiddle. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJ_Shijo/8bg6q3wh/13/) there shows 4 lines named as input1, input2, input3, & input 4 and it is updated with live random data but in my actual project the input values are updated via MQTT. Here I am adding points to chart with  series[i].addPoint() method.I want to add some markers or symbols along with line if the value exceed a particular limit.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series;
            var length = series.length;
            setInterval(function() {

              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                a0 = Math.random();
              a1 = Math.random();
              a2 = Math.random();
              series[0].addPoint([x, Math.random()], true, true);
              for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                series[i].addPoint([x, Math.random()], false, true);
              }
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'input1',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }, {
        name: 'input2',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }, {
        name: 'input3',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }, {
        name: 'input4',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }]
    });
      });
     });
```

Comment: Could you give more specifications what you want to achieve? How do you want to update your data in chart? You can change markers using marker.symbol parameter. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.marker.symbol

Comment: I don't see an actual question in your post, or any indication of what you've tried, what's not working, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use setState() method and utilize the tooltip. Then you can style the tooltip or the circle that encloses a point in focus with the API for the tooltip and have the styles or the tooltip symbol/html change according to the value on the chart with conditional statements.
See this answer: [Highcharts - manually trigger hover event on a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194527/highcharts-manually-trigger-hover-event-on-a-point)